# how to add the QScrollBar in QScrollArea with default layout

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I have a `QScrollArea` and i want to add the `QScrollBar`. I don't have a layout, like this picture:

[image]

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

A `QScrollArea` doesn't need external `QScrollBar`s. It has its own ones. Just set `verticalScrollBarPolicy` and `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` to `ScrollBarAlwaysOn`.

[image]